# How to pass data from form input over uploadify

Tags: jquery, uploadify

Here's my code:

```
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({

        'swf'      : 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : 'uploadify/uploadify.php',
        'formData' : { 'workId' : $("#zkouska").val() }

    });
```

and

```
    <input type="text" name="zkouska" id="zkouska" />
```

It doesn't pass anything, because it takes value from #zkouska input only during initialization of uploadify script. But I want to pass input value after I enter it. How am I supposed to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out by myself.

I read the manual of formData and there was this code that you have to add (but it didn't work):

```
'onUploadStart' : function(file) {

    $("#file_upload").uploadify("settings", "workId", $("#zkouska").val());

}
```

So I searched a little bit a find a thread with this correction:

```
'onUploadStart' : function(file) {

    $("#file_upload").uploadify("settings", "formData", {"workId": $("#zkouska").val()});

}
```

Works fine now.